# How to implement Peer to peer database replication between two sites?

Tags: sql-server-2008, vmware-esxi, windows-cluster, microsoft-cluster-server

I am looking for SQL Server database solution which can replicate data between two sites vice versa (not just one way)

I’ve looked into SQL Server failover cluster (MSCS) but then since I have two different sites (Production and DR) it would be to hard or maybe impossible to implement peer to peer data content replication ?

My plan is to build this solution on top of VMware ESXi with Windows Server 2008 for our server monitoring in both sites.

In terms of database mirroring though, I certainly considered this approach but decided that peer to peer replication would provide more availability for the collection of data reading from systems going into the DB. The scenario was if one of the sites was disconnected from the outside world, I wanted the monitoring software (which uses SQL Server 2008) to still continue to collect the data from all the systems within that site still. Database mirroring wouldn't allow as only the primary database is writeable. Peer to peer replication would allow me to take advantage of load balancing, which could potentially give performance gains and not just redundancy

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Demo: Real ​Time ​Analytics ​with SQL ​Server 2008 ​R2 Stream​Insight](http://channel9.msdn.com/learn/courses/SQL2008R2TrainingKit/SQL10R2UPD00/SQL10R2UPD00_REC_03), [March Madness on Demand](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rdoherty/archive/2009/03/13/march-madness-on-demand.aspx) and [High volume real time contiguous ETL and audit](http://www.slideshare.net/rusanu/high-volume-real-time-contiguous-etl-and-audit). All these solution are solving similar problem (collect monitoring data) and face similar issues (gracefully handle back end collector unavailability for seconds, minutes or days at a time). so basically, how to write into a database in a highly available manner, even if the database is temporarily unavailable. What they have in common is that they use reliable messaging: they write into a local SQL Express queue and then let [Service Broker](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166049.aspx) deliver the write into the final destination.

Comment: wow that sounds cool, is that features only available on SQL 2008 R2 Enterprise ? or I can use the Peer-to-peer transaction replication between my two servers ?